# Laravel - use the Eloquent where method from within View

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 5.4, I have these tables:

```
sales_orders : id,order_code, customer_id

out_transactions : id, ref_id
```

`ref_id` refers to the primary key (i.e. `id`) of `sales_orders`.

First I need to get all the rows from `sales_orders` with a particular `customer_id` i.e. 10; Then for each row, I need to query the `out_transactions`  table matching its `ref_id` against the `id` of  `sales_orders` table.

Inside the `show_all` method of the  controller `RequisitionController`, I have :

```
$query_sales_order=SalesOrder::where('customer_id',10);

$requisitions = $query_sales_order->get();

$model=InventoryOutTransaction::query();

return view('admin.requisition.requisition',compact('requisitions')->withModel($model);
```

Inside the `requisition.blade.php`, I have :

```
foreach($requisitions as $aP) {


    $requisition_id = $aP->id;
    $inventory_out_info = $model->where('ref_id', $requisition_id);

    echo '<br/> sql = '.$inventory_out_info->toSql();

    $inventory_out_result = $inventory_out_info->get();

    $inventory_out_info_id = 0;

    foreach ($inventory_out_result as $inventory_out_result_indiv) {

        $inventory_out_info_id = $inventory_out_result_indiv->id;

        echo ' inventory_out_info_id =  '.$inventory_out_info_id;

    }

}
```

But the sql shows unexpected query . 
What I get in a case  is

```
sql = select * from `out_transactions` where `ref_id` = ?
sql = select * from `out_transactions` where `ref_id` = ? and `ref_id` = ?
sql = select * from `out_transactions` where `ref_id` = ? and `ref_id` = ? and `ref_id` = ?
```

So you can see that the `where` clause is being concatenated. And the concatenated clause remembers the 1st, 2nd etc values of `ref_id` from the `for loop` to use each of them, I guess ( I just cannot print the exact value of `?` in the query).

How can I  just remove the concatenation ? or Any other way to achieve the same purpose ?

Comment: Surely the blade is purely for representing the data and not for fetching data!

Comment: Then how could I get the data in the controller to pass it to the blade view ?

Comment: Do the foreach in the controller and build up an array of data you need to display, then pass the array to the blade.

Comment: Is that the Laravel style ?

Comment: Laravel uses an MVC approach (http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/) the idea is to make each part only responsible for it's bit.  So the view part is purely for viewing data (so laying it out according to the device your using).

Answer (score 0):

First try this query in your controller and print the answer once your expected result is come change your controller with this query and pass the result into view page and foreach the results with your need.

```
    $result  = DB::table('sales_orders')->join('out_transactions','sales_orders.id','=','out_transactions.ref_id')->where('sales_orders.customer_id',10)->get();
```

Comment: Oh my.. How to do in  Eloquent way ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed  $result  = SalesOrder::join('out_transactions','sales_orders.id','=','out_transactions.ref_id')->where('sales_orders.customer_id',10)->get();

Comment: @sunilwananje, even when  `out_transactions` does not have the matching `ref_id`, I need the columns from `sales_orders` as well. What to do - left join?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed if you want all record fro sales order which are not having record in out_transactions so you can use leftJoin instead of join in previous comment query

Comment: @sunilwananje, your comment deserves to be an answer.